# Automapper - Map objects with IEnumerable<anotherType>

Tags: c#, automapper

SOLVED: I had a property defined incorrectly!

I'm getting this error...
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
HouseDomain -> RoomDomain 
{namespace}.HouseDomain -> {namespace}.RoomDomain

Destination path:
City.Houses.Houses.Houses0[0]

So for example, I have

```
public class CityDomain
{
    public IEnumerable<HouseDomain> DomainHouses {get;set;}
}
public class HouseDomain
{
    public IEnumerable<RoomDomain> DomainRooms {get;set;}
}    
public class RoomDomain
{
    //whatever
}
```

and

```
public class CityDto
{
    public IEnumerable<HouseDto> DtoHouses {get;set;}
}
public class HouseDto
{
    public IEnumerable<RoomDto> DtoRooms {get;set;}
}
public class RoomDto
{
    //whatever
}
```

So I want to map CityDomain to CityDto. I have...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CityDomain , CityDto>();
```

Is there an issue going 2 levels deep like this? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need the second `.ForMember` snippet if you have the `CreateMap` you've posted a the bottom. AutoMapper automatically handles lists/enumerables if the element types are mapped.

Comment: This works for me http://pastebin.com/6uZyDhbi

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, Automapper handles lists/enumerables automaticaly if they have the same names only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all mappings you need (Automapper is smart enough to map lists of objects if mapping for appropriate object types was created):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RoomDomain, RoomDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<HouseDomain, HouseDto>()
      .ForMember(d => d.DtoRooms, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.DomainRooms));
```

Just remove your second mapping for member DtoRooms. E.g. if house has id and room has name, then for sample domain house mapping works just fine:

```
HouseDomain domainHouse = new HouseDomain
{
    Id = 42,
    DomainRooms = new List<RoomDomain>
    {
        new RoomDomain { Name = "foo" },
        new RoomDomain { Name = "bar" }
    }
};

var dtoHouse = Mapper.Map<HouseDto>(domainHouse);
```

Produces:

```
{
   Id: 42,
   DtoRooms: [ { Name: "foo" }, { Name: "bar" } ]
}
```

Last note - make sure you create maps before you are doing mapping. Usually all maps are created on application startup.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your mappings simplier if you make names of collections the same (e.g. `Rooms`) for both `HouseDomain` and `HouseDto` types.

Mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RoomDomain, RoomDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<HouseDomain, HouseDto>();
```

Types:

```
public class HouseDomain
{
    public IEnumerable<RoomDomain> Rooms {get;set;}
}

public class HouseDto
{
    public IEnumerable<RoomDto> Rooms {get;set;}
}
```

I answered the similar question [AutoMapping nested models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571248/automapping-nested-models/19631606#19631606) a while ago.