# Automapping - for IEnumerable map multiple properties with different name

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two class 
Say:

```
  public class SourceData
        {
            public string SourceCode { get; set; }        
            public string SourceName { get; set; }
        }
```

and

```
public class DestData
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string DestName { get; set; }
    }
```

I try to map IEnumerable of SourceData to DestData, but it is not working

I try with

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<SourceData >, IEnumerable<DestData>>()
```

Comment: Isn't this a valid solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173057/automapper-map-objects-with-ienumerableanothertype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both classes have fields with different names. AutoMapper won't pick them up automatically. So you need to explicitly tell it how to map fields in both classes. You do this like this.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceData, DestData>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.DestName, a => a.MapFrom(src => src.SourceName))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, a => a.MapFrom(src => src.SourceCode))
```

Note that you're creating maps between types themselves not between collections of types as AutoMapper will automatically handle collections. Next just use following to map:

```
var destList= Mapper.Map<List<DestData>>(sourceList);
```

or

```
Mapper.Map<List<SourceData>, List<DestData>>(sourceList, destList);
```

depending on your situation.

Comment: Now your answer is completely correct - that's because I deleted my incomplete answer.

Comment: please describe what problem are you facing and where.

Answer (score 1):

Mapper.Map>(someDataEnum)Have you mapped SourceData to DestData? You don't have to map collections.

```
var configuration = Mapper.Configuration;

configuration.CreateMap<SourceData, DestData>()
    .ForMember(lite => lite.Code, src => src.MapFrom(post => post.SourceCode))
    .ForMember(lite => lite.DestName, src => src.MapFrom(post => post.SourceName))
```

and to map

```
var destDataCollection= Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SourceData>, IEnumerable<DestData>>(sourceDataCollection);
```